# Filter rows in column 1 based on cell value in column 2, but keep corresponding duplicates in col 1

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns. First is name of equipment. Second is a maintenance code.

```
col 1           col 2 
1112-19-ET01B   
1112-19-ET01B   PSGREKB
1112-19-ET02A   
1112-19-ET02A   
1112-19-ET02A   PSGREKA
1112-19-ET02B   PSGREKA
1112-19-ET02B   
1112-19-ET02B   
1112-19-FE07
1112-19-FE07
1112-19-FE07
1112-19-FE07                
1112-19-JU01    
1112-19-JU06    
1112-19-PA02
```

I want to search through col 1 and filter all rows that have a code in col 2. But if the row in col 2 contains a code, I want to keep all corresponding duplicates in col 1 as well.

So above dataframe would be:

```
col 1           col 2 
1112-19-ET01B   
1112-19-ET01B   PSGREKB
1112-19-ET02A   
1112-19-ET02A   
1112-19-ET02A   PSGREKA
1112-19-ET02B   
1112-19-ET02B   
1112-19-ET02B   PSGREKB
```

I have tried using groupby and filter out blanks in col 2, but that don't let me keep the duplicate rows in col 1 but rather remove all rows without at value in col 2.

```
df2=df.groupby('Functional Loc.').filter(lambda x: (x['Revision']!=''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`groupby.transform('any')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = df[df['col 2'].ne('').groupby(df['col 1']).transform('any')]
```

Or [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df['col 1'].isin(df.loc[df['col 2'].ne(''), 'col 1'])]
```

*NB. assuming empty cells are `''` as hinted in your code, if `NaN` replace `ne('')` by `notna()`.*

Output:

```
           col 1    col 2
0  1112-19-ET01B         
1  1112-19-ET01B  PSGREKB
2  1112-19-ET02A         
3  1112-19-ET02A         
4  1112-19-ET02A  PSGREKA
5  1112-19-ET02B  PSGREKA
6  1112-19-ET02B         
7  1112-19-ET02B
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
# Creates a list of IDs with a code
ids = df[~df['col 2'].isnull()]['col 1']
# Leave only IDs with code
df = df[df['col 1'].isin(ids)]
df


           col 1    col 2
0  1112-19-ET01B     None
1  1112-19-ET01B  PSGREKB
2  1112-19-ET02A     None
3  1112-19-ET02A     None
4  1112-19-ET02A  PSGREKA
5  1112-19-ET02B  PSGREKA
6  1112-19-ET02B     None
7  1112-19-ET02B     None
```